# Stop event in angular2 web worker

Tags: angular, web-worker

How can you stop the event propagation in web worker?

In the event what you get in web worker doesn't have stopPropagation method.

thank you

UPDATE

Specifically click event I am interested now.

The event object contains:

```
altKey: false
button: 0
clientX: 780
clientY: 82
metaKey: false
movementX: 0
movementY: 0
offsetX: 361
offsetY: 51
region: undefined
screenX: 784
screenY: 177
shiftKey: false
```

UPDATE 2

In angular2 you can run the whole application in a web worker. This means you have to communicate with the browser via the renderer interface. Seemingly there is no possibility to stop the bubbling from this interface.

Strangely in alpha.xxx they removed (^click) syntax, which means that the events are bubbling just with ^, and without ^ all the events are not bubbling by default... But it was just removed and not changed to the opposite.

Also wondering if angular material will support web workers as in their code they have event.stopPropagation ...

Comment: Updated title to angular2, as probably it is specific to it as the events are serialized.

Comment: Huh? There are click events in WebWorkers? Where do they come from?

Comment: Coming from the ui part of the framework. https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/web_workers/ui/event_serializer.ts

Comment: Then obviously you cannot cancel native event from a different thread. Unless Angular uses events to raise events you can only read the event from WebWorker. Quite possibly, the event already bubbled up at the moment when you receive it over `onMessage`. You're using WebWorkers but you want everything to be synchronous?

Comment: yes, understand, but still I don't want that click to go further to the parent. Hope it doesn't mean that everything is synchronous...

Comment: You say you understand but obviously you don't. This is what happens: Main thread generates click event. Main thread sends message about that event to worker and processes the event. When worker receives the event, main thread is already processing and "bubbling" the event. I don't know why are you trying to handle events in separate thread. Separate thread is for **processing**. It's been many years and so far there were no problems with having even handling in main thread - it's UI operation in the end.

Comment: This doc might shed some light on how events are handled https://docs.google.com/document/d/1M9FmT05Q6qpsjgvH1XvCm840yn2eWEg0PMskSQz7k4E/edit (just an architecture proposal not about the actual implementation but might give some hints)

Comment: Hmm, maybe having an own renderer extending the DomRenderer..., but would be too much hassle for something which is actually frequently used. Also found EventManagerPlugin, but thats also a bit overkill, and couldnt make it working yet...

Answer (score 1):

That particular type of event does not bubble, so it does not have the `stopPropagation` API. According to the MDN documentation:

> The event doesn't bubble and is cancelable; to prevent the default action from taking place, the worker can call the error event's preventDefault() method.

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) on section "Handling Errors" for some more info on that.

Comment: But click should propagate, I updated the question with object I get from event.